# Can't add ServiceReference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

As I understand, WSDL address is on remote server, but it has links to XSD's inside as "localhost", and my VisualStudio can't resolve it. If I download wsdl and change "localhost" to remote address - it works fine, but xsds has another links inside with localhost.

And I don't think that downloading whole service is the right way :)

What can I do?

**Added**: And SoapUI can't load this service ether: *"Error loading [http://localhost:7733/ESchoolService?wsdl=wsdl0]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream"*

Comment: How are your services deployed?
Internet/Intranet?
Please show the system.servicemodel config.

Comment: This is not mine service, so i don't have any sources. It hosted on a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple to be fixed, just changing the baseaddress url in the configuration file for the service. I understand that you don't have access to the source code, but do you have access to the configuration file? If you do, just find the baseAddress element, and replace the localhost by the server name (or a known DNS). Here is an example:

```
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://MyServerName:7733/ESchoolService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers,

Rob.

Comment: Well, this question is from 2012 :) Thank you for your answer - that's possibly the right way! Hope, you understand that I can't check it now, but I didn't know about this property - thank you, Roberto!